# Change filesystem type from "Linux" to "Linux root (x86-64)"

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk, partition-table

I just partitioned a new GUID drive, and accidentally chose "Linux filesystem" (`0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4`) instead "Linux root (x86-64)" (`4F68BCE3-E8CD-4DB1-96E7-FBCAF984B709`) for my root partition. I already downloaded and installed the system. Is it possible to change the partition type without reinstalling/repartitioning?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I must have been blind.

In `fdisk` there is an entry

```
t   change a partition type
```

Just select it, choose the partition, and enter `24` (or `l` to check the number first)